# I want to write own adress of the pointer in them

Tags: c++

```
int main ()
{

    int *tab[5];
    int i=0;
    for (;i<5; i++)
    {
        tab[i]=&tab[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to assign their own adress to every element of the tab. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: What type does `&tab[i]` have? Hint: it's not `int*`.

Comment: What you're trying to do is really impossible, since the type needs to be infinitely recursive.

Comment: ohhh so I can't write adress of the pointer as worth of the pointer?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Not necessarily. You can with some `void*` tricks :P

Comment: @Rakete1111 Of course, but the keyword there is *tricks*. :) "Tricks" doesn't make good code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with an array of `int*`. Because `&tab[i]` would then be an `int**`. And those pointer types are incompatible.

However, a `void*` pointer can hold the address of *any* other object pointer, even a `void**`. Therefore this declaration:

```
void* tab[5];
```

Will turn your program into a well-formed one.

Comment: But then the question is, why would you want to do that? :D

Comment: @Rakete1111 - Ah, that is a question for philosophers, not language lawyers :P